# How to initialize a custom prototype style table cell in iOS 5 storyboards?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I am converting over to iOS 5 and storyboards. When I have a table view with default cell style, everything works fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifierFromStoryboard"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifierFromStoryboard"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I have seen examples where the "if (cell == nil)" block is removed. However if I take it out, my app crashes with the message: "UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:". This is not a problem because it works as shown above.

My problem is that I want to use a custom style for the cell and thus cannot use initWithStyle. How do I initialize a custom cell that I have designed on the storyboard?

The old pre-5 app had a nib and class that used something like this, but now I'm using the storyboard.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomTableCell *cell = (MyCustomTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (MyCustomTableCell *) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what if you still try to use this Nib as the custom TableViewCell ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This way

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That results in a cell with the default style and not the custom style from the storyboard.

Comment: heres and example http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells

Comment: Thanks for the link. I got it to work. A little tricky step is control dragging from an empty space on the view.

Comment: Can you be more precise? I still don't get it. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but it will be more easy to solve doubt if you give a little more info

Comment: This answer is outdated and now wrong. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: @jackslash  We're not all using storyboards.

Comment: Nope. Now you register table cell classes with the table view in advance and when you dequeue the cell is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you were pointing something else out. Should try to edit the answer then.

Answer (score 9):

This worked perfect for me (Xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if( cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1000];
    UILabel *summary = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1001];
    [title setText:[ tableMainTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [summary setText:[ tableSubTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Important: Do not forget setting delegate and datasource.

Comment: For iOS6 with storyboards, cell is never nil after dequeuing.

Comment: @mskw so a cell will always be valid and useable? or do they have some other method of identifying invalid cells (like a constant or something)

Comment: Given you have the correct identifier yes. Otherwise it will crash complaining about it.

Answer (score 8):

If you load your view controller that contains the tableview using:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
```

Then inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you just need one line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifierFromStoryboard"];
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will instantiate one cell if there is none exists.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as far as I can tell. Checking for nil cells etc is useless boilerplate when using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one works very well. I was trying to get my head around it for sometime and thanks it worked.. well i was doing this, when trying to alloc a cell i was allocating using the general cell class instead of the one i had created

so i was doing this, so thats reason why it did not work

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

so instead of UITableViewCell alloc the cell with your class, well with the above example "CustomCell"

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *identifier=@"SearchUser";
SearchUserCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[SearchUserCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
return cell;
```

Comment: So what does that code mean? Some commentary would have helped.